# iOS cellForRowAtIndexPath with static cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a weird bug. I have a grouped UITableView with static cells and I want to add a white shade under each section. The way I thought about doing it is to add a shadow to each lowest cell in a section.

So in `viewDidAppear` (because in `viewDidLoad` it wouldn't work) I wrote:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// change the cells shadow
```

The problem is that in viewDidLoad I call becomeFirstResponder on a text field. When cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, the textfield looses focus.

I tried using becomeFirstResponder in viewDidAppear after the call to cellForRowAtIndexPath but that doesn't help, the textfield still looses focus.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
[textfield performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

Comment: this perform with a 0 delay, delays the message to the next runloop iteration

Comment: it is ... but one I use quite often when dealing  with UI. I wouldn't accept it for anything related to business logic

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method for adding the shadow.